# Counting vowels followed by consonants

Tags: python-2.7

I want to count the vowels in a text, this I can do. But I also want to count the amount of vowels followed by a consonant and the amount of vowels followed by a vowel. Can somebody help me with this?

This is what I have so far but it says invalid syntax for the line where I use i+1 in vowels.

```
s = "text"
vowels = set("aeuio")
consonants = set("qwrtypsdfghjklzxcvbnm")

vowelcount=0
vowelvowelcount=0
consonantcount=0
consvowelcount=0
consconscount=0
vowelconscount=0

for i in s:
    if i in vowels:
        vowelcount += 1
    if i in consonants:
        consonantcount +=1

for i in s:
    if (i in vowels,and i+1 in vowels):
        vowelvowelcount +=1

print ("number of vowels:",  vowelcount)
print ("number of consonants:", consonantcount)
print ("number of vowels followed by vowels:", vowelvowelcount)
```

Comment: You'll want to use string slices and count your way through the string. Something like if s[2:3] in vowels and s[3:4] in vowels.

Comment: @mba12: but `s[3:4]` is equivalent to `s[3]`...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem You are correct, your syntax is cleaner too. I wrote my comment before I saw your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `for i in s`, `i` is **not an index**: it is a character. A quick way to solve this is using:

```
for i in range(len(s)-1):
    if s[i] in vowels and s[i+1] in consonants:
        vowelconscount += 1
    elif s[i] in vowels and s[i+1] in vowels:
        vowelvowelcount += 1
    # ...
```

Here we use `range(..)` to iterate over all indices up to (but excluding) `len(s)-1`. For each of these indices `i` we check if the character in `s` at position `i` (that is `s[i]`) is `vowels` and the next character `s[i+1]` is a cononant.

Answer (score 1):

I like Willem's answer. I have another option. I might want to use `enumerate` in this case.

```
for i, char in enumerate(s[:-1]):
    if char in vowels and s[i+1] in vowels:
        vowelvowelcount +=1
```

Comment: This will not work without another `if` statement since `i+1` will run out of range of `s` in the last iteration.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Oh, forgot to add `s[:-1]`. Thanks!

Comment: perhaps you can use `enumerate(s[:-1],1)` since then you can save the `+1` is `i+1`.